# Real Matrix Root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $p$ be a prime number, find a $(p-1)\times(p-1)$ real matrix $A$ such that

$$A^{p-1} + \cdots + A + I=0$$

For $p=3$, with brute force computation I find that

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
-1 & 1\\
-1& 0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

is a solution. How do we find the solution for arbitrary $p$? Or can we at least prove that there is a solution for any prime number $p$?

Comment: The expression is "brute" force rather than "brutal", by the way

Comment: One approach is to simply use the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial

Comment: Another approach is to use a suitable rotation matrix. In particular, the matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta}, \quad \theta = \frac{2 \pi}{p}
$$
satisfies $B^{p-1} + \cdots + B + I = 0$. The same holds for the block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{B & 0\\0 & I}
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix of the appropriate size.

Comment: Think in a rotation matrix, should be similar to what happens with complex numbers !

Comment: @Ben Grossmann what if the brute force he used really was brutal?  There might be shattered pencils everywhere

Comment: If you only look in matrices $A$ such that the determinant of $A-I$ is nonzero, then this is equivalent to finding matrices $A$ such that $A^p=I$

Comment: Can you check the exercise statement, please. Because it asks for a $(p-1)\times(p-1)$ matrix, I tend to think that a matrix with **integer** entries is wanted. Otherwise we get away with $2\times2$ as @BenGrossmann explained. On the other hand, with $p$ a prime and integer entries the size requirement is a perfect fit to the companion matrix of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p(x)$. Which would be my educated guess for the desired answer. Why else would it be essential for $p$ to be a prime (and you using the tag [tag:number-theory])?

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: the matrix 
$$
B = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta}, \quad \theta = \frac{2 \pi}{p}
$$
satisfies $B^{p-1} + \cdots + B + I = 0$, but the same does **not** hold for the block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{B & 0\\0 & I}.
$$
However, because $p-1$ is even, we could use the block-diagonal matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{B \\ & \ddots \\ &&B}.
$$